# skip empty array in nested array in reduce()

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have nested Array (arrays in parent array).

```
let myArray = [ [], [ 8300, 8400, 8500, 8600 ], [ 6379 ], [ 5672 ], [ 27017 ] ]
```

I am trying to mix all of this into one array .

```
let targetArray = [8300, 8400, 8500, 8600, ..., 27017]
```

I used reduce and concat to achieve this goal.

```
let unique_array = myArray.map(p=>{p}).reduce((prev, next)=>{prev && prev.concat(next))
```

but I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught Error TypeError: Reduce of empty array with no initial value
```

so my question is how can I skip this error?

Comment: You can use `.flat()` or a polyfill if your browser doesn't support it

Comment: You need to provide an initial value to reduce, and in this case, it would be an empty array, i.e. `reduce(() => {/**/}, [])`

Comment: @Kobe _"You need to provide..."_ - No, you don't have to. The initial value is [optional](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Comment: Your example doesn't throw that error. The error only occurs when you call `.reduce()` on an _empty array_ without providing an initial value -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Reduce_of_empty_array_with_no_initial_value

Comment: Your approach was right.

You can do it like this: `let targetArray = myArray.reduce(function(acc, cur) { return acc.concat(cur); }, []);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not [Array.prototype.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat):

> The `flat()` method creates a new array with all sub-array elements concatenated into it recursively up to the specified depth.

```js
let myArray = [ [], [ 8300, 8400, 8500, 8600 ], [ 6379 ], [ 5672 ], [ 27017 ] ];

let targetArray = myArray.flat();

console.log(targetArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do this

`unique_array = myArray.reduce((prev, next)=>([...prev,...next]),[])`